# Want to get table row id when click on any cell of table

Tags: jquery

suppose i have html table and each TR has id. every TR has some TD and some TD has input controls and some may have text inside in.

when click on TD or control should return immediate TR id.

i tried this below script which works fine but when i click on text like hello1 then TR id does not return.

see the script and tell me what is missing.

```
<div id="grd1">
    <table>
        <tr id="t1"><td tabindex="0"><span>Hello1</span></td><td tabindex="1"><input /></td><td tabindex="2"><input /></td></tr>
        <tr id="t2"><td tabindex="3"><span>Hello2</span></td><td tabindex="4"><input /></td><td tabindex="5"><input /></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

$('#grd1 table tr').on('focus', ':input', function(event) {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using an advanced selector, I suggest you do some changes:

1. Change `:input` to `input`.
2. The `id` call, change it to below.
3. I believe the `<tr>` is also dynamic, so add it with the delegation.

Corrected Code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<div id="grd1">
  <table>
    <tr id="t1"><td tabindex="0"><span>Hello1</span></td><td tabindex="1"><input /></td><td tabindex="2"><input /></td></tr>
    <tr id="t2"><td tabindex="3"><span>Hello2</span></td><td tabindex="4"><input /></td><td tabindex="5"><input /></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
  $('#grd1 table tr').on('click focus', 'td, input, th', function(event) {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
  });
</script>
```

[image]

**The Alert** Duh!!!

[image]

Comment: @Thomas **Works perfectly. See in Console (middle column): http://jsbin.com/bawinotefe/edit?html,console,output**

Comment: when clicking on hello1 or hello2 then not getting TR id :(

Comment: What do you see in the middle? Console tab or your browser's console? It perfectly gives me the ID. Lemme add a screenshot for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98491/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-thomas).

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/on18nsme/1/  this is your code. run and click on hello text....see does it provide any alert with immediate TR id# :(

Comment: in my pc alert is coming when click on textbox but no alert is coming when click on hello1 text.

Comment: @Thomas **Do you get the alert here: http://output.jsbin.com/wovazihepo/1** Now don't say you don't get it.

Comment: i said repeatedly that i am getting ID when clicking on textbox but no id is throwing when clicking on hello1 text but hello1 text also is in td of that same table.

Comment: @Thomas Have updated the final code. Sorry for confusion. you were targeting only the `input` not the non-input.

Answer (score 1):

Use the table cell(td) as the selector and listen for `click` event.

```
$(document).on('click', '#grd1 td', function(event) {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/vubecuzeza/1/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Answer (score 0):

Give the table an id eg 'table':

```
$('#table').children('tbody').children('tr').each(function () {
   var $row = $(this);
   $row.find('input').on('focus', function () {
       alert($row.get(0).id);
   });
});
```